# Avoid including coverage folder created from running yarn coverage using vitest in git commit

Tags: code-coverage, vitest, .git-folder

Our team is using vitest, vitest-environment-nuxt, nuxt-vitest for component unit testing,provider for creating coverage report is v8,using package @vitest/coverage-v8.
What I want to achieve is excluding coverage folder generated after running command `vitest run --coverage`.

Trying to add "coverage" in .gitignore file but it seems doesn't work for me. Whenever I run `git status`, there will be lines indicate that files in coverage folder are modified.
Any advice would be perfect. Thank you!